# Add "Image Windows" to pxe boot menu

Tags: pxe-boot, ghost

I have a Fog server running (which contains my OS images). However, when booting from a client I want to reimage it without using the web gui. So I need to add an entry to my `pxelinux.cfg\default` file which will image the PC.

How can this be done? I know how to boot an ISO, but not start fog to image my PC (through the PXE menu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer at [their wiki](http://www.fogproject.org/wiki/index.php/Bypass_Host_Registration).

I needed to change the init.gz with noreg.gz (see wiki) to make it work.